# Derive circle where circle contains half of the points in a dataset

Tags: arcgis-pro, analysis

I have a point dataset for my area of interest (AOI). A lot of the points are near the center of the AOI (it’s the downtown area of a major city). I have found the central mean. Then using that mean as a the origin, derive a circle where the area inside the circle contains half the data points and the other half outside the circle. I want to be able to take the circle and say “Half of all points in this dataset occur inside this circle” (I’m betting it’s a relatively small circle).

I’m using ArcGIS Pro and am comfortable using Python to create this analysis if necessary.

Comment: Your post contains multiple questions and will likely be closed.  Please take the tour:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and refine your question.  Edit your question to focus on one portion of your problem.  FYI, Weighted central mean is available in the Mean Center tool in ArcGIS Pro.  The Near tool is available in the Analysis toolbox.  Minimum bounding geometry as a circle is also available in ArcGIS Pro Data Management toolbox.

Comment: What have you tried? If you're comfortable using Python, what have you coded so far?

Comment: Run Near between points and center. Find median of Near distance

Comment: I found a workable solution closest to what @FelixP mentioned. I calculated the mean center, then I used "Generate Near Table" using the single mean center point and calculated the distances from the input point dataset. Then I simply looked up the distance calculated of the midpoint based on the "NEAR_DIST" field and created a buffer  on the mean center slightly larger than the point with the middle distance, but not large enough to capture the next nearest point.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a larger and larger buffer from the points center and stop when half of the points are within it.

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np
#arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True #If you rerun the code many time you will need this line to overwrite each dissolve

pointfc = r"C:\GIS\GIStest\one_thousand_points.shp"
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(pointfc).spatialReference

#Find the center of the points
dissolved = arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features=pointfc, out_feature_class="memory\dissolved")
multipoint = next(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dissolved, "SHAPE@"))[0]
centerpoint = multipoint.centroid
centerpointgeom = arcpy.PointGeometry(inputs=centerpoint, spatial_reference=spatialRef)

#List all points and count them
all_points = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointfc, "SHAPE@")]
numpoints = len(all_points)

#The step to increase the buffer size with for each iteration
step = 10 #Start with a large step and lower it.
stop = max([multipoint.extent.width, multipoint.extent.height]) #When to stop.

#Buffer by an increasingly larger buffer radius and stop when half of the points are within
for bufferdist in np.arange(start=step, stop=stop, step=step):
    buffered = centerpointgeom.buffer(bufferdist)
    points_within = [pnt for pnt in all_points if pnt.within(buffered)]
    pointcount = len(points_within)
    if pointcount>=numpoints/2:
        print(f"A buffer of radius {bufferdist} contains {pointcount} of {numpoints}")
        break

A buffer of radius 1200.0 contains 509 of 1000
```

[image]

Comment: This task calls for a binary search algorithm, getting larger *and smaller*, and needs to consider the real possibility that exactly half the point count is not possible.